# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una comprensión de listas del siguiente código?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy trabajando con la comprensión de listas para optimizar mis códigos. Trato de comprimir este ciclo **for**

```
for divisor in range(1,x+1):
    if (x % divisor) == 0 :
        result.append(f"{divisor}, ")
        up += 1

print("el numero ",x," tiene ",up," divisores")
```

Intenté comprimirlo, pero no resultó:

```
print("el numero ",x," tiene ",comprimido=[divisor for divisor in range(1, x+1) if (x % divisor) == 0:  up+=1]," divisores")
```

¿Me pueden explicar qué es lo que salió mal?

De antemano, agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis es la que está mal, algo que tienes que saber es que una comprensión de lista es para hacer algo en específico, no varias operaciones y no en todos los casos es conveniente usarla.

La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```py
[i for i in iterable condicion]
```

La condición es solo un `if`, lo que quiere decir es que simplemente agrega el elemento si la condición se cumple, equivalente a `if x: list.append(element)`

Otra cosa es que no puedes hacer la asignación de una variable en el `print()` ya que se tomará como parámetro.

Dicho todo lo anterior tu comprensión de lista debería quedar así

```py
print(f"El número {x} tiene como divisores", [div for div in range(1,x+1) if x%div ==0])
```

No puedes usar un contador en una compresión de lista por lo que si quieres hallar el número de divisores tendrás que hacerlo calculando el tamaño de la lista con `len()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho, para este caso sí lo utilicé para calcular las iteraciones de un número random, en un ciclo for definido por la cantidad de iteraciones que el usuario elija, no sé si me expliqué bien, pero acabo de ver con la explicación que comentas, que no se puede poner un contador en una compresión. Aún así, me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La comprensión de listas sirve para empaquetar. Sería algo fuera de su uso común tratar de hacer una operación diferente a una creación de listas.

Por otra lado, puedes intentar prescindir de esta ya que, de cierta manera, sólo estás filtrando. Para eso mejor usa la función `filter`:

```py
num = 10

divisores = list(filter(lambda divisor: not num % divisor, range(1, num+1)))

print(f'El numero {num} tiene "{len(divisores)}" divisores')
print(f'Los cuales son: {",".join(map(str, divisores))}')
```

Resultando en algo como:

```sh
$ python3 list_compre.py
El numero 10 tiene "4" divisores
Los cuales son: 1,2,5,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Con comprensión de listas:

```
divisores = [divisor for divisor in range(2, x) if not x % divisor]
```

Los divisores del número X están entre 2 y X-1, por lo que puedo acortar el rango.

No necesito llevar un contador por separado, para eso tengo la función `len`, que me dice cuantos elementos (divisores) hay en la lista.

**Demo**

```
x=45
divisores = [divisor for divisor in range(2, x) if not x % divisor]

print("el numero ",x," tiene ",len(divisores)," divisores")
print(divisores)
```

produce

```
el numero  45  tiene  4  divisores
[3, 5, 9, 15]

Process finished with exit code 0
```